# Android: Can I reduce "Overall bit rate" of an audio file recorded by MediaRecorder?

Tags: android, audio, device, audio-recording, bitrate

I have a problem with audio file size. After researching, I found this helpful link [Android - Recorded audio file differs size when changing device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988459/android-recorded-audio-file-differs-size-when-changing-device). However, I still cannot resolve my problem. Channel: 1, Sample rate: 11025Hz, Bit rate: 64Kbps. I run the code on 3 difference devices, the duration is the same, but the output files are all different. Sony Zperia: 437BK, Samsung Galaxy Tab A: 40.3KB, and Nexus 7: 43.9KB.

[image: Samsung]
[image: Nexus]
[image: Sony]

I see the biggest different between those files is the Overall bit rate in the General information. Am I right that the Overall bit rate causes this problem? Can we reduce the Overall bit rate?

I appreciate every single answer. If you need any information, please let me know.

Thank you in advance!